# Traveling outside Italy with permesso di suggorno

Tags: visas, schengen, ukraine, iranian-citizens, italian-residents

I am Iranian student in Rome and I have the permesso di suggorno. I want to know if I can travel to Ukrain with my permesso di suggorno or not?

Comment: Related: [Traveling to the Netherlands with a Permesso di Soggiorno](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/141087/travelling-alone-to-the-netherlands-with-a-permesso-di-soggiorno?rq=1)

Answer (score 3):

According to https://mfa.gov.ua/en/consular-affairs/entering-ukraine/visa-requirements-for-foreigners Iranian citizens need a visa to enter Ukraine unless they hold a diplomatic or service passport.